# Show DataGrid-Details when SelectionUnit is "Cell"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with two DataGridTextColumns which get their Content via Bindings.

DataGrid:

```
    <Grid Margin="30">

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="MainDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="200" RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow">

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#172B4D"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Click to sort."/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2582b0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding Birthday, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="ID:" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Geburtstag:" />

                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Birthday, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) },
                new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) },
                new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) },
            };

            MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want the visibility of the details to change depending on which cell is clicked on (cell with name or cell with birthday) and then has focus.

I have tried to change the SelectionUnit property to "Cell", but then the details are no longer displayed.

I would like to know if it is possible to display details for only one cell.

I hope I have explained the problem in a comprehensible way...